# jQuery for validating latitude and longitude regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-validate

I'm validating using jQuery as follow:

```
$("#register-form").validate({
rules: {
latitude: {
    required: true,
    strongCoord: true
  },
  longitude: {
    required: true,
    strongCoord: true
  }
},
messages: {
  yrAr: {
    required: 'Please enter year.'
  }
}
});

$.validator.addMethod('strongCoord', function(value, element) {
return this.optional(element) 
  value.length >= 4
  && /^-?([0-8]?[0-9]|90)\.[0-9]{1,6},-?((1?[0-7]?|[0-9]?)[0-9]|180)\.[0-9]{1,6}$/.test(value);
}, 'Your coordinate format has error\'.')
```

And in the form the text fields are as follow:

```
input class="form-control" name="latitude" placeholder="Enter Latitude" type="text">
<input class="form-control" name="longitude" placeholder="Longitude" type="text">
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
```

It keeps returning `Your coordinate format has error'.` even though i used coordinates i got from google. I'm sure its just syntax. Can anyone point me i the right direction?

Thank in advance...

Comment: I don't think `$.validator` is native `jQuery` so if you're using a plugin you should add a tag or a link for that plugin.

Comment: Yes, Because regex seems pretty right.

Comment: Add the sample co-ordinates to your post.

Comment: o used the coordinate given by google for London eye 51.5033 by 0.1195

Answer (score 1):

In your function you do:

```
return this.optional(element) 
  value.length >= 4
  && /^-?([0-8]?[0-9]|90)\.[0-9]{1,6},-?((1?[0-7]?|[0-9]?)[0-9]|180)\.[0-9]{1,6}$/.test(value);
```

However that doesn't look like correct syntax to me.  [The documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/) gives an example like:

```
  return this.optional(element) || /^http:\/\/mycorporatedomain.com/.test(value);
```

I think you need to change your code to:

```
return this.optional(element) || 
  (value.length >= 4
  && /^-?([0-8]?[0-9]|90)\.[0-9]{1,6},-?((1?[0-7]?|[0-9]?)[0-9]|180)\.[0-9]{1,6}$/.test(value));
```

Comment: I made a slight change; wrap the 2nd part of the return statement in `( )`

Comment: the error went away but now it doesn't detect erroneous input... i could even key in letters...

Comment: Sounds like it's not even getting as far as the regex then. What do you get if you add `console.log(this.optional(element))` immediately before your `return` statement?

Comment: it returns `4 false`

Answer (score 1):

Solved it... I created 2 separate functions for latitude and longitude instead of one function for both:

```
$.validator.addMethod('latCoord', function(value, element) {
  console.log(this.optional(element))
return this.optional(element) ||
  value.length >= 4 && /^(?=.)-?((8[0-5]?)|([0-7]?[0-9]))?(?:\.[0-9]{1,20})?$/.test(value);
}, 'Your Latitude format has error.')

$.validator.addMethod('longCoord', function(value, element) {
  console.log(this.optional(element))
return this.optional(element) ||
  value.length >= 4 && /^(?=.)-?((0?[8-9][0-9])|180|([0-1]?[0-7]?[0-9]))?(?:\.[0-9]{1,20})?$/.test(value);
}, 'Your Longitude format has error.')
```

Then i called it as such:

```
latitude: {
    required: true,
    latCoord: true
  },
  longitude: {
    required: true,
    longCoord: true
  }
```

It still bothers me why i can't use a single function for both :(